Hybrid model (between-within model) with spatial lags?
In the analysis I'm currently doing, I'm planning to use a hybrid model (i.e. a between-within model) since my data includes both time variant and invariant variables. I am also interested in this model since I can estimate within- and between-entity effects separately, and compare them. My data is panel data across 10 years and over 2000+ census blocks.
I am anticipating that there's strong spatial autocorrelation in my dependent variable and I'm not exactly sure if I'm able to include spatially lagged values to my model in this case.
I am also not sure how to implement this in R. Is it as simple as just adding the spatially lagged terms to a hybrid regression model?
